# How can I capture this through a regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have some text like this:

```
ABCPQR01 is not at all good
EFHSTU39 is somewhat nicer
```

and I want to capture the `ABC...` and `EFH...` type words. The first set of three letters can be `ABC` or `EFH` and the second set of three letters can be `PQR` or `STU`. Instead of writing two separate regexes to capture these two text elements, how can I write this as a single `re.compile` statement? Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you be more clear - what all do you want to capture?

Comment: @Nightfirecat: The posted answer works fine for me. I am trying to capture the `ABC...` and `EFH...` parts of the sentences. The rules on how to form these words are given in my description.

Comment: Its not too clear, are the 2 separate regexs you infer these: `ABC(PQR|STU)` and `EFH(PQR|STU)` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> re.match('(ABC|EFH)(PQR|STU)', 'ABCPQR01 is not at all good').groups()
('ABC', 'PQR')
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be a pattern which would work :)

```
>>> re.compile("^(ABC|EFH)(PQR|STU)\d\d\b")
```

also you can test it at http://www.regextester.com/index2.html